# How to post build result to team room in TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Is there a way to post build results from the build system (vNext?) in the Team Rooms?

I noticed there is an option to post build results in the team rooms, but the available list to choose from are only XAML build definitions and not the new build system (vNext?) definitions.

Comment: Can't see a way at the moment.

Comment: You can use REST API and custom code to post to team rooms. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/chat/messages

Comment: Well, sad to know it's not currently implemented, if I implement it in the foreseable future, I'll post the solution here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. 
I have logged the issue here : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1874524

Comment: Please vote for this on [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/9622173-vnext-build-completion-events-in-team-room)!

Answer (score 0):

I have try it on my environment(TFS2015&VS2015) .
Sorry about that, this function seems only support XAML build by now.

You can raise your requirements to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The following Powershell code is a first attempt at getting something working for us:

```
Param($teamroom,$message)
# Example: Write-MessageToTeamRoom.ps1 -teamroom "Team Room Name" -message "Notify @User name about work item #54142" 
# https://jaspergilhuis.nl/2014/02/18/utilize-the-tfs-team-room-rest-api/
# https://jaspergilhuis.nl/2014/02/23/encapsulate-team-room-api-calls-with-a-powershell-commandlet/
$rooms = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET http://tfsapp02:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_apis/chat/rooms?api-version=1.0 -UseDefaultCredentials
$room = $rooms.value | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $teamroom}
$relevantRoomID = $room.id
$jsonbody =  @{ content="$message"} | ConvertTo-Json
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST "http://{TfsDefaultCollectionPath}/_apis/chat/rooms/$relevantRoomID/messages?api-version=1.0" -Body $jsonbody -ContentType "application/json" -UseDefaultCredentials
```

My ambition is to expand this code to run whenever a build completes and then write the build result into the team room